# No memory leaks

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

In my college we were asked to create a program which allocates all of the free memory.
So I figured that making an infinite loop and allocating memory without freeing it must consume up all the free memory of the computer.
However since I am not freeing the memory, there must a huge memory leak.

So I wrote a simple program but when I checked it with valgrind there were no memory leaks. None whatsoever. No direct no indirect leaks.

Please tell me why. Here is my program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i,kb=0,mb=0;
    char *some;
    while(1) {
        for(i=0;i<1024;i++)
        {
            // Allocating memory one kilobyte a time.
            some = (char*) malloc(1024);
            if(some == NULL)
            {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            kb++;
        }
        // Displaying no. of mbs that have been allocated at each mb
        mb++;
        printf("%d mb\n",mb);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because the compiler figures out that the memory returned from `malloc` is never used and therefor simply skips compiling that section of the code?

Comment: I voted +1 because I think it's an interesting question and I would really like to know the answer=)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry for not replying for such a long time. I got caught up in my University exams. I am using Clang as a compiler. The fact that I can't use gcc is that in my ubuntu installation, valgrind somehow always refuses to install. And in my vmware installation of fedora valgrind is installed ( I got this vmware image from another location in it fedora, clang, valgrind, xxd, lamp etc.. were pre-installed ).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `some = (char*) malloc(1024);` with this: `some = new char[1024];`
It will fail at 2000MB if you have at least that much free memory. However this won't allocate all of the free memory in the computer if you run this in Win32 environment, because there is a 2GB limit for each process, so in that case you will need another approach.

Comment: Why should the behavior be different? Anyway, this is C code, so `new` won't work.

Comment: You are right, it won't work in C, sorry for that. I tried it in C++ and it threw an Exception with new but not with malloc. That's why I thought it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that the allocation has been optimized away - typically either entirely or pushed to stack storage. In this case, removing it entirely is better.

You generally prove or disprove this by reading the generated assembly.

Comment: I am not that good in programming. I am learning. Your first line makes sense. But I can't understand your second line. Can you please help me more.

Comment: @Ishan your compiler can output assembly code for you. this is essentially your source code (program) built as configured (e.g. with optimization settings) and converted to machine instructions. it takes some time to learn to read assembly code, so this may not be the best option if you have never done it before. i have been doing this 10 years; i am still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

when i run it - valgrind finds problems:

```
==3335==
==3335== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3335==     in use at exit: 2,271,338,496 bytes in 2,218,104 blocks
==3335==   total heap usage: 2,218,105 allocs, 0 frees, 2,271,338,496 bytes allocated
==3335== 
==3335== 
==3335==     Valgrind's memory management: out of memory:
==3335==        newSuperblock's request for 8876032 bytes failed.
==3335==        3116339200 bytes have already been allocated.
==3335==     Valgrind cannot continue.  Sorry.
==3335== 
==3335==     There are several possible reasons for this.
==3335==     - You have some kind of memory limit in place.  Look at the
==3335==       output of 'ulimit -a'.  Is there a limit on the size of
==3335==       virtual memory or address space?
==3335==     - You have run out of swap space.`
```

Even using O2 O3 does not remove that error. Is it a full sample?

upd

the flag does not change output, but if i interrupt the program before the crash, valgrind shows next:

```
^C1890 mb
==3286== 
==3286== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3286==     in use at exit: 1,981,808,640 bytes in 1,935,360 blocks
==3286==   total heap usage: 1,935,360 allocs, 0 frees, 1,981,808,640 bytes allocated
==3286== 
==3286== 276,480 bytes in 270 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 3
==3286==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3286==    by 0x8048472: main (mem_test.c:13)
==3286== 
==3286== 1,981,530,112 bytes in 1,935,088 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==3286==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3286==    by 0x8048472: main (mem_test.c:13)
==3286== 
==3286== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3286==    definitely lost: 1,981,530,112 bytes in 1,935,088 blocks
==3286==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3286==      possibly lost: 276,480 bytes in 270 blocks
==3286==    still reachable: 2,048 bytes in 2 blocks
==3286==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3286== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==3286== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==3286== 
==3286== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3286== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Hey can you show the results when valgrind is run with --leak-check=full

Comment: @Ishan the flag itself does not change the output

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, the kernel do not limit allocations but the effective use of the memory.
(see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting)

```
$ echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Should disable this, or else your code should run as expected if you pad allocated memory with 0:

```
some = (char*) malloc(1024);
if(some == NULL) {
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
memset(some, 0, 1024);
kb++;
```